# CSS not working in Django

Tags: css, django

```
        {% extends "base.html" %}
        {% load i18n %}
        {% load staticfiles %}
        {% block jsscript %}
    <!-- Script code -->
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $(function() {
                        $('#btnNext_picklocation').attr('disabled','disabled');
                        $("#location input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
                            if($('#location input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'))
                            {
                                $('#btnNext_picklocation').removeAttr('disabled');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $('#btnNext_picklocation').attr('disabled','disabled');
                            }
                        });
                        $("#location .maps img").attr("src","{% static 'media/loading.gif' %}");
                        $("#location .maps img").error(function(){
                            $(this).unbind("error").attr("src","{% static 'media/loading.gif' %}");
                        });
                        {% for obj in filter_location %}
                        var url{{obj.city}}="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{obj.suite}},{{obj.street}},{{obj.city}}&size=400x200&maptype=roadmap&markers=size:mid|color:green|{{obj.suite}},{{obj.city}}&sensor=true";
                        $("#map{{obj.city}}").attr("src",encodeURI(url{{obj.city}}));
                        {% endfor %}
                        $('#btnNext').click(function(){
                            window.location.assign("./pickpaymentplan/");
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" />
        {% endblock %}
        {% block head %}
                <h1 class="heading" >Place An Order</h1>
                <h4 class="heading">Please choose a location</h4>
        {% endblock %}
        {% block content %}
<!-- Main Body Content -->
            <form id="frmLocation" action="./" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table border="1" id="location" >
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                                        <th>Locations</th>
                                        <th>Map</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% if filter_location %}    
                                    {% for p in filter_location %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" id="{{p.location_id}}L" name="{{p.location_id}}L" ></td>
                                        <td>{{p.suite}},{{p.street}},<br/>{{p.city}},{{p.state}},<br/>{{p.country}},{{p.zip}}</td>
                                        <td class="maps" ><img id="map{{p.city}}" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    {% else %}
                                    <tr></tr>
                                    <tr><td  colspan="5">No Locations!</td></tr>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </table></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right"><input type="submit" id="btnNext_picklocation" name="btnNext_picklocation" class="btnNext" value="Next"/>              </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="footer" name="footer">
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
```

I this code I have used a base.html file as a base template. Appropriate changes has been made to settings.py, like static_url, media_url. Still this page is not working as expected.
Can indentation be an issue?
Is there some extra steps to be followed for implementing css?

Comment: What is not working? No, indentation cannot be an issue.

Comment: Please show us your `base.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you are overriding `{% block jsscript %}` in some descendant template. If that is not the case, then I would confirm that the output of `{% static 'css/base.css' %}` is actually giving you what you expect (can you visit that URL?)

Two other thoughts:

1. Spaces don't really matter in templates.
2. You should probably move your CSS into something like `{% block stylesheets %}` instead of `{% block jsscript %}`.

Comment: janos: i am able to view my templates without css. Even-though I have created a base template but the contents of my project's template are not showing any styling.

Comment: cwallenpoole: Sir, you are right, I am trying to override my javascript, because there are some basic scripts that has to be executed in every page. At the same time there are some pages which have their own respective scripts, and it's behavior has to be appended.

Answer (score 0):

If you're overriding the template block, and want to maintain the block's original content, you can use `{{block.super}}` to output the original content, like this:

parent.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}MySite{% endblock %}</title>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

child.html

```
{% extends 'parent.html' %}
{% block title %}Child Page - {{block.super}}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}Hello world!{% endblock%}
```

The `title`for a page rendered using child.html will be "Child Page - MySite"

Answer (score 0):

The general steps to diagnose such issue in *any* framework are:

- verify that the `<link>` tag is present in the generated page - use View Page Source in your browser or use HTML panel in Firebug*
- verify that `href` attribute of the `<link>` tag looks ok-ish
- Use Firebug's Net panel to see if your stylesheet is actually loaded
- Enter the stylesheet's URL (as found in your generated page) directly in the browser's address bar to see if its actual contents is what you expect
- If all of the above found no problems, use Firebug's CSS panel to see if there's another stylesheet which overrides your styles.

If you follow these steps, chances are high you'll be able to find the problem yourself, if not - you'll be able to ask a much more concrete question

---

`*` by "Firebug" I mean Firebug itself, Chrome Dev Tools or Opera Dragonfly, whatever suits your tastes.